# passing a function as a parameter to launch on UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I'm actually trying to develop a function on Android to compute some things, however, this method could be (or not !) called from a Task.
This method has to Toast something at each step done, I found the method `.runOnUiThread(Runnable ...)`. Written in my function directly.

This is working, but what if in the future someone doesn't want Toasts and prefers update a loading bar for example?
It's why I would know if it's possible to pass to my function a method which will can run on the UI thread, and the easiest way as possible for the user of my function ? Maybe there is an efficient syntax with lambda expression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, I found a solution.

I have an interface to define a method `action(int x, int y)` for example.
Then I have to pass in argument a type of this interface to my method, and this method just call the `myInterface.action(..., ...)` with the updated values.

Then in the second Thread which is launching my method to compute things I have something like this :

```
myMethod(<some others args> ,
                (int x, int y) ->
                        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> { /*Some code */ })
        )
```

So I can choose directly where I call the method, what will be the behavior of this kind of handler. And in this case I use `runOnUiThread()` because I'm in a Task.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways: 
 
You already mentioned the first way:

```
activity.runOnUniThread(Runnable runnable);
```

You can use the following method as well:

```
view.post(Runnable runnable);
```

or:

```
view.postDelayed(Runnable runnable, int delay);
```

Example:

```
textView.post(r -> { 
    Log.e("Activity" ,"Text"); 
});
```

Just write your code into the runnable. You can even predefine it:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable(r -> {
  // make your stuff
});
// ...
button.post(r);
```

Last option: **Handler**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
// You know the scheme :
handler.post(r);
// or
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```